# Почему invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

Всем привет.
Решил почитать "Грокаем Алгоритмы". Захотелось посмотреть, как работает бинарный алгоритм на деле, переписал его в Sublime Text 3, вроде всё ок, но произошла непонятная фигня.
Пишет invalid syntax на сточке **print binary_search(list, 3)# => 1**. Сможете помочь разобраться и что-нибудь посоветовать?
Заранее всем спасибо!
Код ниже:

```py
print("Проверка бинарного алгоритма")
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(list)-1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None

print binary_search(list, 3)# => 1
print binary_search(list, -1)# => None
```

Comment: В python3 `print` - это функция, и вызывать её надо как функцию

Comment: Спасибо за правку вопроса!

Answer (score 3):

Если Python у вас 3-ей версии, а код программы явно из 2-й, то вам надо ставить скобки у `print`:

```
print(binary_search(list, 3))
```

Это основное различие между версиями, остальные не так заметны.

Comment: Спасибо большое!